# Dataframe partitioning pruning

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a two table(table_a, table_b) hive which is partitioned by build_date(integer of format YYYYMMDD) and it parquet and snappy compressed.
I use this table in a my pyspark program as

```
hiveCtx = HiveContext(sc)
df1 = hiveCtx.table('table_a').filter(func.col('build_date') == 20170101)
df2 = hiveCtx.table('table_b')
df3 = df1.join(df2, df1.build_date == df2.build_date)
```

When I do a `df3.explain()` it reads all the partitions in table_b. How do I make it read only that particular partition ?

I have also set the hive property set('spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet', 'false')